# HttpWebRequest error 403

Tags: c#, .net

I am new in C# and have requirement to retrieve a url from C#.  Most of case it’s working fine but in one case its throws an error. url is as follows
**http://whois.afrinic.net/cgi-bin/whois?searchtext=41.132.178.138**

**Error is:**

Exception in the HTTP request for url: http://whois.afrinic.net/cgi-bin/whois?searchtext=41.132.178.138 The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

My code  is as

```
void MyFUnction(string url)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

    request.UserAgent = ".NET Framework Test Client";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    Logger.WriteMyLog("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");


    // execute the request
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    // we will read data via the response stream
    Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();

    string tempString = null;
    int count = 0;
    do
    {
        // fill the buffer with data
        count = resStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);

        // make sure we read some data
        if (count != 0)
        {
            // translate from bytes to ASCII text
            tempString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf, 0, count);
            if (httpData == null)
                httpData = tempString;
            else
                httpData += tempString;

        }
    }
    while (count > 0); // any more data to read?
}
```

Comment: to format your code, select it in the editor, and press Control-K.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove your ContentType line.

```
request.ContentType....
```

You're not doing a form post, only retrieving the page with "GET".

```
request.Method = "GET"; //this is the default behavior
```

And also set the Accept property to "text/html".

```
request.Accept = "text/html";
```

Comment: this is nice. I succeed on doing this, after adding this three lines initilization : ' webRequest.Method = "GET";
            webRequest.UserAgent = "Foo";
            webRequest.Accept = "text/html";'

Comment: Although this post is quite old I have upvoted it today i.e., on October 15, 2016, because today I had also faced a similar problem when trying to learn Webscraping. I posted the problem on stackoverflow but somebody pointed there is a similar question already and hence I deleted and searched the answers available already. The answer given above my Shri Mikael Svenson was really really helpful to solve my own problem. Okay @Mikael Svenson

Answer (score 4):

Set

```
request.Accept = "text/html";
```

as well and it will work.

I don't know why they are configured that way, might be deliberate to discourage some bots. You might want to check their terms of service whether you may query their site automatically.

---

Edited to add: Still convinced that my answer was correct in this case, I can reproduce the 403 every time if I don't set the Accept header. The ContentType is superfluous, but not harmful.
In any case, you'll also want to change your function to properly dispose the response, and to read the response with the correct character encoding:

```
void MyFunction(string url)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.UserAgent = ".NET Framework Test Client";
    request.Accept = "text/html";
    Logger.WriteMyLog("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    // execute the request
    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        // we will read data via the response stream
        Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(
                                      resStream,
                                      Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet)
                                    );
        httpData = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```